# html - Text align in DIV using bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am not a good UI HTML developer but have to do some fixes on a form. I am surprised that text align is not working on this form. I can see this HTML but don't know how to align text right on label **StockEnd**.

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="StockEnd">End</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 ">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="StockEnd" class="form-control" id="StockEnd" ng-readonly="readonly" ng-model="Catalogdata.stockTo" ng-disabled="isDisabled" capitalize typeahead="item.number for item in getAutoCompleteStockNumber($viewValue)">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn-default btn" type="button" ng-click="stockNumberSearchClick('end')"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry a correction here its 'StockEnd' not start but need to do similar places.

Comment: Have you tried the `text-right` Bootstrap class?

Comment: yes every thing that has align or text property

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with marginal adjustment to your HTML classes.

First, you must remove `.col-sm-1` on your `<label>`, as this class causes a `float:left` to be applied to the element, which means any use of `text-align` will no longer affect it. With that class removed, you can then add `.text-right` to the parent of the `<label>`.

In the end, your HTML will look like:

```
<div class="col-sm-1 text-right">
  <label class="control-label" for="StockEnd">End</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 ">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="StockEnd" class="form-control" id="StockEnd" ng-readonly="readonly" ng-model="Catalogdata.stockTo" ng-disabled="isDisabled" capitalize="" typeahead="item.number for item in getAutoCompleteStockNumber($viewValue)">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn-default btn" type="button" ng-click="stockNumberSearchClick('end')"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/O3GpmaNvoM) to demonstrate.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

either add `text-right` class to the parent `form-group`

OR

modify the label to be `display: block` with `text-right` class to do this.

Comment: i see you are not using the label without form-group, you can apply text-right on the col-sm-*

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with my colleague, we made this change and it worked as required. Just removed the class from outer Div and it worked. So Instead of

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="StockEnd">End</label>
</div>
```

it is now

```
           <div >
                <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="StockEnd">End</label>
           </div>
```

Rest is same no change.